# unsupported match type for string: CONTAINS_DEEP

Tags: karate

I am attempting to use Karate to do comparisons of some deeply nested JSON objects. It seems like "contains deep" is exactly what I'm looking for except it doesn't seem to work if one of the nested arrays only contains String values like shown here (simple case, not the actual response I'm trying to work with):

```
Feature:

  Background:
    * configure logPrettyRequest = true
    * configure logPrettyResponse = true

  Scenario:
    * def actual =
      """
      {
        "person": {
          "hobbies": [{
            "name":"basketball",
            "equipment":[
              "basketball",
              "shoes",
              "jersey"
            ]
          }]
        }
      }
      """
    * def expected =
      """
      {
        "person": {
          "hobbies": [{
            "name":"basketball",
            "equipment":[
              "shoes",
              "jersey"
            ]
          }]
        }
      }
      """
    Then match actual contains deep expected
```

It fails with the following error message:

```
unsupported match type for string: CONTAINS_DEEP
```

Is this something that is just currently unsupported, with plans to allow this in the future? Or is there another way to accomplish this? Ideally I am trying to stay away from having to compare separate parts of the json individually as the payloads I am working with are pretty large.

Comment: Have you tried using the `develop` branch of the framework? I see `CONTAINS_DEEP` in the latest HEAD of the `develop` branch. https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/Match.java#L53

Comment: @tammenBruccoleri you are correct, this seems to be fixed in the latest release candidate. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this problem is fixed in the latest release candidate of karate-core. See this issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1475.

Adding this to my pom solved the problem for me:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.9.RC4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```